# Unable to drop all capabilities but CAP_SETUID

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

I am strace-ing a process that fails over a call to `capset`.

To make sure that the process has the correct capabilities I added a `capget` just before the `capset`.

The result of strace is now:

```
[pid 27909] capget(
    {version=_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid=0},
    {effective=1<<CAP_SETGID|1<<CAP_SETUID|1<<CAP_SETPCAP|1<<CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|1<<CAP_NET_ADMIN|1<<CAP_NET_RAW|1<<CAP_SYS_ADMIN, 
     permitted=1<<CAP_SETGID|1<<CAP_SETUID|1<<CAP_SETPCAP|1<<CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE|1<<CAP_NET_ADMIN|1<<CAP_NET_RAW|1<<CAP_SYS_ADMIN, 
     inheritable=0}) = 0
[pid 27909] capset(
    {version=_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid=0}, 
    {effective=1<<CAP_SETUID, 
     permitted=1<<CAP_SETUID, 
     inheritable=0}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

So the process has some capabilities, including `CAP_SETUID` in both the effective and permitted set.

Now we try to set the effective and permitted set of capabilities to to `CAP_SETUID`.

And I don't understand why this is failing.

We are basically dropping all the capabilities but one, whats wrong with it?

Comment: What if you also keep `CAP_SETPCAP`?

Comment: The issue was a seccomp filter running. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a seccomp filter running.

Unfortunately I could not find a better way to deal with this kind of issues beside thinking hard about it and hope to not miss anything.